# Colon between title and subtitle

Tags: punctuation

A colon is often put between the title and the subtitle of essays and articles.

Is it necessary? Can I drop it?

Answer (score 2):

It's convention for a reason. Without the colon, it can be hard to figure out where the main title ends and the subtitle begins.

> Oliver Twist The Parish Boy's Progress

Oliver should twist what?

> Oliver Twist: The Parish Boy's Progress

That is better.

Note that an semi-colon is often used when introducing an alternate title:

> Peter Pan; or, the Boy Who Wouldn't Grow Up

Comment: Correct, but what about a pdf file where you can put the subtitle in the line below the title?

Comment: I answered your question. Your question didn't mention that situation. If that's what your question is, that's what you should ask.